# Github: I've been granted "pull access" to a private repo but I can't clone the repo (but I can download a zip of the source code)

Tags: git, github, git-pull, git-clone

I'm not sure what it means to have "pull access" on a private repo. Should I be able to clone it now? I can't.

```
[1045](m7int01)~/codes>git clone https://github.com/glwhart/[repo_name]
Initialized empty Git repository in /zhome/glh43/codes/[repo_name]/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while 
accessing https://github.com/glwhart/[repo_name]/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

But I can download a zip file of the source code...

Comment: perhaps you need to pass your username?  If so, `git help clone` and search for `username`

Comment: you should be able to `git clone https://username:password@github.com/glwhart/[repo_name]`, although passing your password in the clear isn't the best idea

Comment: In my previous organization, all the http requests to github was blocked by firewall, I also used to get the same messages

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you have a git credential helper which might have cached the wrong credentials:

```
git config credential.helper
```

As suggested, `git clone https://username:password@github.com/...` can be used to force the use of those (correct) credentials, just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to take up bandwidth for a simple question. At any rate, the "copy to clipboard" button on the github page (for cloning the repo) seems to have given me a bogus url. I tried again this morning and it was different---but it still didn't work.

Similar to several suggestions/comments above, including my username (but not password) in the url did the trick:

```
git clone https://[username]@github.com/[orgname/reponame].git
```

This connected correctly, asked for my github password, and worked.

Thanks to those who took time to respond.

I'm still wondering if "pull access" is different than any other kind of access. The email that invited me said that I had been granted "pull access"...